# /bin/bash - Alfred 3 workflow does not detect php

Tags: php, bash, alfred

So I downloaded this plugin https://github.com/vmitchell85/alfred-vuejs-docs and I got the Powerpack. Here is me trying to execute the workflow but pressing enter at this point does nothing:

[image]

After I press space and enter "vue events", I get in the debug:

`[2018-09-02 16:56:33][ERROR: input.scriptfilter] Code 127: /bin/bash: php: command not found`

Which is strange because I fire up my `Terminal.app` (Which uses bash) and I do `php -v` which gives me: `PHP 7.2.8 (cli) (built: Jul 19 2018 12:15:24) ( NTS )`. Same thing on my `zsh` profile.

What do I do?

Comment: What do you get for `$ which php`?

Comment: @xilopaint `which php` = `/usr/local/bin/php`

Comment: Does it work if you use `/usr/local/bin/php vuejs.php "{query}"` on the Script Filter instead of `php vuejs.php "{query}"`?

Comment: Not sure how to do that @xilopaint .. will get back to you.

Comment: Look at the image you posted. There's a Script Filter object on the Alfred Editor. You just have to doble-click on it and replace `php vuejs.php "{query}"` with `/usr/local/bin/php vuejs.php "{query}"`.

Comment: @xilopaint Hey -- that worked! Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't fix the root cause. It looks like `/usr/local/bin` is not in your $PATH. If you want to confirm this check the output of `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179334/discussion-between-xilopaint-and-nn2).

Comment: @xilopaint You're right -- but it seems like it is? iTerm: (zsh) `/Users/dan/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/dan/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/dan/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` and terminal (bash) `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: It's weird. `/usr/local/bin` is in your `$PATH` but for whatever reason `php` cannot be found. Well, I just posted the answer for this question. Could you accept and upvote it since it worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the image you posted. There's a Script Filter object on the Alfred Editor. You just have to double-click on it and replace `php vuejs.php "{query}"` with `/usr/local/bin/php vuejs.php "{query}"`.